# Did some people in New York in 1918 board a subway feeling healthy and then die from the flu during the subway ride?

Tags: flu

We can [read here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/retropolis/wp/2018/01/27/the-flu-can-kill-tens-of-millions-of-people-in-1918-thats-exactly-what-it-did):

> In New York there were accounts of people feeling perfectly healthy when they boarded the subway in Coney Island and being taken off dead when they reached Columbus Circle.

Comment: Flu can be a killer, but that quickly?  Doesn't sound remotely credible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anecdote originates from *The Coming Plague: Newly Emerging Diseases in a World Out of Balance* by one Laurie Garrett (1994).

> There were reports of women boarding a New York subway in Coney Island
>   feeling little else than mild fatigue, and being found dead when the
>   train pulled into Columbus Circle, some forty-five minutes later.

"There were reports" is a pretty safe phrase to use! In other words, this book is relating a rumor.

Garrett does not give a direct source for this. The next citation in the book is to *Influenza: The Last Great Plague* by W. Beveridge (1977), but Google Books is telling me that the anecdote is not in that source.

---

edit: I don't know why DavePhD deleted his answer, but he provided a similar anecdote from [the *New York Times Magazine* in 1992](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/11/29/magazine/the-flu-pandemic.html?pagewanted=all):

> One man got on a streetcar feeling well enough to go to work, rode six
>   blocks and died.

This led me to another, from Lynette Iezzoni's *Influenza 1918: the worst epidemic in American history* (1998):

> On a Cape Town trolley, the driver, conductor, and five passengers
>   collapsed and died within a three-mile stretch of road.

This book is based on a 1998 episode of the PBS series [*American Experience*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0325619/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

None of these three secondary sources cited a primary source, but the core of the anecdote does seem a little more plausible now.

Comment: Any reason why we should believe that influenza was the cause of death, and not, say, an aneurysm?

Comment: Because there is no source, this story could have come from anywhere. Maybe it's a story the author heard from her grandmother. I looked up the speed of 1918 influenza symptoms but I don't see any reason to believe this.

Comment: @Oddthinking what do you think the odds are that seven people on one Capetown tram would all die of aneurysms in a period of 10.or 20 minutes?

Comment: @phoog: The statement that there were 7 people was added after my aneurysm comment. I remain skeptical about this evidence. The quote about the 7 people does not suggest that they were symptomless before getting on the trolley. If they were, I would strongly suspect exposure to a different agent. (I am not even mentioning the unbounded time it takes a trolley to travel three miles when the driver is dead.)